# Design op-amp circuit from transfer function

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, pid-control, transfer-function

What is the best way to design a circuit based on the following transfer function:

$$T(s)=\frac{9216}{(s^2 + 48s + 9216)}$$

Comment: Can you please tell what you have tried? Can you share with us some of your research? This helps the community to provide an answer that is meaningful to you.

Comment: Do you just need a filter, or is this a power circuit of some sort?